# using jquerymobile dialogbox in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, requirejs

I need to add a modal dialog on my project. So the situation is that I render a login page. the login page will consist of two input textfield and two buttons ( login and connection ) now what i need is that whenever i click connection(button) i need to show a modal dialog box that will have a input textfield and a list of previously entered data. This is what i did so far but its not working.

```
connection.tpl.html 
<div id="connectionContainer" data-role="page" style="width:200px; height: 200px;">
<input id="serviceUrl" class="user-input"/>
```

loginview

```
var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events:{
    "click .login-btn" : "Login",
    "click .connection-btn" : "Connect"
    },

    initialize: function(){
    },

    Login: function(){
        Const.USERNAME = $("#username").val();
        Const.PASSWORD = $("#password").val();
        if(!Const.USERNAME || !Const.PASSWORD)
        {
            alert("Invalid Username/Password!");
            $("input").val("");
        }else{

            var auth = EncodeAuth(Const.USERNAME,Const.PASSWORD);

            var sendAuthorization = function (xhr) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth)
            };

            this.model.save(this.model, {
                beforeSend : sendAuthorization,
                success: function(model,result){
                    if(result.ErrorMessage === null)
                    {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(result.Message));
                        $("input").val("");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(result.ErrorMessage));
                        $("input").val("");
                    }
                },
                error: function(model,result){
                    alert("Remote server returned an error. Not Found");
                    $("input").val("");
                }
            });
        }
    },
    Connect:function(){
        this.connectionview = new ConnectionView({ el: $("#connectionContainer") });
        $("#wrapper").html( _.template( ConnectionTemplate ) );
    }
```